# sqlite with where clause not working

Tags: android, sqlite

Below is my code snippet. 
My query does return a single value but I don't know how to extract that value.
The `showtoast(ID)` does not show anything. Please help

```
try {
    String ID = null;
    mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor allrows = mydb.rawQuery(
        "SELECT REGID FROM " + TABLE + " where NAME = '" + name_from_spinner + "'" ,
        null
    );

    if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
        showToast("not empty");
        ID = allrows.getString(0);
        showToast(ID);
    } else {
        showToast("empty");
    }

    allrows.close();
    mydb.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(
        getApplicationContext(),
        "Error encountered.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    );
}
```

Comment: read documentation on how to read values from cursor

Answer (score 1):

You will never get a null cursor from `rawQuery`. Instead use `moveToFirst`:

```
if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
    showToast("not empty");
    ID = allrows.getString(0);
    showToast(ID);
}
```

Also since you're selecting only 1 column, you know it's index will be 0.

If you expect to receive multiple columns, you can loop the cursor like this:

```
if (allrows.getCount() == 0) {
    showToast("empty");
} else {
    while (allrows.moveToNext()) {
        ID = allrows.getString(0);
        showToast(ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: i did like you said.my code is not entering the if statment,i used an else statment just to see if my code enters the if block,it does not.my else block is executed.please tell me what could possibly be the problem

Comment: @nainasony that means no rows have been found.